# Shopify loop through Field group - Advance custom fields

Tags: shopify, shopify-template, shopify-api

Im using Advance custom fields app on shopify and created repeatable set of fields using Field group option given.

The issue is I can not find a way to loop through filed groups. One field groups contain all the sub fields inside it.

Custom field setup look like this,

[image]

This for a cocktails list so, I have made cocktail as field group and added name, description inside. You can repeat cocktail field group then name. description and other sub fields get repeated along with it which is perfect.

This is how it looks to enter the data
[image]

Comment: Have you find any solution to it so far?

Answer (score 0):

Field Group as you see in shared screenshots is only for Advanced Custom Fields app. For you to access the data, if it is a repeatable field you get the Array as value, if unrepeatable you get the raw value.

[Repeatable vs Unrepeatable Fields](https://support.arenacommerce.com/support/solutions/articles/6000243408-unrepeatable-vs-repeatable)

[image: Repeatable vs Unrepeatable Fields]

For your scenario, you can do something like this. Each field value would be an array.

```
  {%for value in page.metafields.arena.name%}
    {{value}}
  {%endfor%}

  {%for value in page.metafields.arena.description%}
    {{value}}
  {%endfor%}
```

Comment: The problem is that, by that way, we can only get arrays for each sub field inside the group. If only there was a way to loop those parent groups...

Answer (score 0):

I found no way to evoque the field group, so what I did was organize my subfields  within the respective repeater fields, accourdin to their Namespace.

So all fields with a Namespace called "faq1" wuould be inside a group field called "faq1". Here is the code to get it on the front end:

faq_quest and faq_anws are my subfield keys.

```
{% assign quest_array = page.metafields.faq1.faq_quest %}
            {% assign anws_array = page.metafields.faq1.faq_anws %}
            
            {% if quest_array.size == anws_array.size %}
                {% assign loopLimit = quest_array.size %}
                {% assign loopLimit = quest_array.size | minus: 1 %}
                <ul class="faq-question-list">
                    {% for i in (0..loopLimit) %}
                        <li class="question">                       
                            <div class="question-trigger">
                                <h2>
                                    {% if quest_array[i] %}
                                        {{ quest_array[i] }}
                                    {% endif %}
                                </h2>
                                <div class="effect"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="answer">
                                <p class="answer-text">
                                    {% if anws_array[i] %}
                                        {{ anws_array[i] }}
                                    {% endif %}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
```